# The questions about li instruction

Tags: ida, mips, encodings

When reversing a MIPS binary using IDA Pro, I have 2 questions. 
The source code is as follows.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int m = 1;
    int n = 5;
    printf("sum = %d\n", m+n);
}
```

### [image: ida pro]

```
.text:00080510  # int __cdecl main(int argc, const char **argv, const char **envp)

.text:00080510  .globl main    
.text:00080510  main:    
.text:00080510      # __unwind {    
.text:00080510 02 00 1C 3C 00 8B 9C 27  li      $gp, 0x18B00    
.text:00080518 21 E0 99 03              addu    $gp, $t9    
.text:0008051C 1C 80 84 8F              li      $a0, 0x80000    
.text:00080520 44 80 99 8F              la      $t9, printf    
.text:00080524 A4 08 84 24              addiu   $a0, (aSumD - 0x80000)  # "sum = %d\n"    
.text:00080528 08 00 20 03              jr      $t9 ; printf    
.text:0008052C 06 00 05 24              li      $a1, 6    
.text:0008052C                  # } // starts at 80510    
.text:00080530
```

---

(1) I know the *li* instruction at offset 0x0008051c is *lw* actually. And its encoding format is 
1000 11ss ssst tttt iiii iiii iiii iiii. So I konw sssss = (111100)2 = 28 = $gp, ttttt = (00100)2 = 4 = $a0.
But I don't know how to calculate 0x80000.

(2) The *li* instrution at offset 0x00080510 takes 8 bytes, but another *li* instruction at offset 0x0008051C takes 4 bytes? Is the first *li* instruction a pseudoinstruction?

Answer (score 3):

MIPS instructions are 4 bytes (32 bit) in size. Hence it's not possible to load a 32 bit constant using a single instruction.

The `li  $gp, 0x18B00` instruction is indeed a pseudo instruction. It's composed of two instructions.

```
lui     gp, 0x2
addiu   gp,gp,-29952
```

**Screenshot from Online Disassembler**

[image]

The `lui` (Load Upper Immediate) instruction loads a 16-bit constant into the upper 16 bits of a register (`$gp` here).

The `addiu` instruction adds a 16 bit integer to a register. The final value in `$gp` can be calculated as:

```
$gp = (2 << 16) + (-29952) = 0x18B00
```

IDA pro and other disassemblers does this calculation automatically and displays the final result using a single pseudo instruction.

The other `li  $a0, 0x80000` instruction at `0008051C` is actually a `lw` (Load Word) instruction. The `lw` instruction loads a word from memory into a register. The value `0x80000` is thus located in memory at `[$gp - 32740]` and not a part of the instruction itself.

IDA however simplifies and shows it as `li  $a0, 0x80000` as the net result is the value `0x80000` is copied to the register.

Comment: Thank you very much! in question (1), how to calculate the 0x80000?

Comment: @user6903 Check update

Comment: Now is static analysis, how does IDA calculate the value of the $gp register, that is, how to calculate $gp - 32740 ?

Comment: The very first instruction sets the value of the `$gp` register `li $gp, 0x18B00`

Comment: There's a way to turn off IDA simplifying gp references. Check [this](https://github.com/angr/angr/issues/1754#issuecomment-548008124)